# Android:Espresso: 3 tests with different json files from assets folder

Tags: android, android-espresso

In folder `app\src\androidTest\assets\`

I has 3 json files for test:

```
trader_0_wallet.json
trader_1_wallet.json
trader_6_wallet.json
```

Here Espresso's test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TraderDetailsActivityTest {

    val targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()
    val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext()

    @get:Rule
    var traderDetailsActivityRule: ActivityTestRule<TraderDetailsActivity> = ActivityTestRule(TraderDetailsActivity::class.java, false, false)

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        val intent = Intent(targetContext, TraderDetailsActivity::class.java)
        val bundle = Bundle()
        val inputStream = context.assets.open("trader_0_wallet.json")
        val content = inputStream.readBytes().toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        val trader: Trader = GsonUtil.gson.fromJson(content, Trader::class.java)
        bundle.putSerializable(TraderDetailsActivity.TRADER, trader)
        intent.putExtras(bundle)
        traderDetailsActivityRule.launchActivity(intent)
    }

    @Test
    fun list_0_wallet() {
        // test activity without wallets
        // need file trader_0_wallet.json
    }

    @Test
    fun list_1_wallet() {
        // test activity with one wallet
        // need file trader_1_wallet.json
    }

    @Test
    fun list_6_wallet() {
        // test activity with six wallets
        // need file trader_6_wallet.json
    }
```

As you can see in `setup` method I read only ONE file `trader_0_wallet.json`. As result test `list_0_wallet` pass, but tests `list_1_wallet` and  `list_6_wallet`failed. 
Because test `list_1_wallet` need file `trader_1_wallet.json` and test `list_6_wallet` need file `trader_6_wallet.json`

How I can load for every tests correct files?

Comment: simply move the setup in the test function. Not in the @Before function

Comment: There are many ways I see your tests can be run; 1. You can split them into three separate tests renaming them as per use case and input. Or, 2, during `setup()` you read all three input files and save them as class variables for the test as inputstream1, inputstream2...trader2,trader2 and using them to initialize your respective bundle, intent and activity in your test methods.

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf maybe better to create 3 separate test classes: TraderDetailsActivityTest, Trader_1_DetailsActivityTest, Trader_6_DetailsActivityTest and test separate every case.

Comment: You should name it a bit more descriptively than Trader_6_DetailsActivityTest. Generally something like; <InputDescription>_<component_to_be_tested>_Test. For example for a password validator `Onlyalpha_passwordcheck_test` or `Alphanum_passwordaccept_test`. The test name should be easy enough for any new developer reading your test reports to identify what they do by a glance. Are you getting what I'm saying?